# Convert SQL subselect to LINQ

Tags: linq, t-sql

I have a SQL subselect query that will retrieve the newest history record for a parent record.

I am having trouble converting the following to LINQ:

```
SELECT *  
FROM ProductRequests INNER JOIN ProductRequestHistory  
ON ProductRequests.ID = ProductRequestHistory.ProductRequestsID
AND ProductRequestHistory.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductRequestHistory.ID  
    FROM ProductRequestHistory 
    WHERE ProductRequestHistory.ProductRequestsID = ProductRequestHistory.ID  
    ORDER BY ProductRequestHistory.DateCreated DESC)
```

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't compile:

```
from productrequests in db.ProductRequests
join productrequesthistories in db.ProductRequestHistories
  on new { productrequests.ID, Column1 = (Int32?)Convert.ToInt32(
((from productrequesthistories0 in db.ProductRequestHistories
where
  productrequesthistories0.ProductRequestsID == productrequesthistories0.ID
orderby
  productrequesthistories0.ID descending
select new {
  productrequesthistories0.ID
}).Take(1).First().ID)) }
equals new { ID = (System.Int32?)productrequesthistories.ProductRequestsID, Column1 =    productrequesthistories.ID }
select new {
 productrequests.ID,
 productrequests.ProductRequestNumber,
 productrequests.ProjectID,
 Column1 = productrequesthistories.ID,
 productrequesthistories.Title,
 productrequesthistories.Requester,
 productrequesthistories.TFSNumber,
 productrequesthistories.UseCase,
 productrequesthistories.RequestType,
 productrequesthistories.FunctionalModule,
 productrequesthistories.Description,
 productrequesthistories.Reason,
 productrequesthistories.Priority,
 productrequesthistories.Status,
 productrequesthistories.Release,
 productrequesthistories.Estimate,
 productrequesthistories.Wags,
 productrequesthistories.Confidence,
 productrequesthistories.Notes,
 productrequesthistories.RequirementStatus,
 productrequesthistories.RequirementDoco,
 productrequesthistories.AlphaRequired,
 productrequesthistories.Sprint,
 productrequesthistories.Created,
 productrequesthistories.DateChanged,
 productrequesthistories.Checksum,
 productrequesthistories.ProductRequestsID
}
```

Comment: ok, we can help you but what have you tried?

Comment: that's because is a sql not a linq take a look to this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746.aspx

Comment: I added the Linq that I tried, but doesn't compile

Comment: Add the foreign keys in your DB, your linq queries will be a lot simplier with Navigation properties...

Answer (score 3):

This in **VB.NET**

```
Dim result = From request in ProductRequests
             Join request2 in ProductRequestHistory
             On request.ID = request2.ProductRequestsID
             And request2.ID = (From request3 in ProductRequestHistory
                                Where request3.ProductRequestsID = request3.ID
                                Order by request3.DateCreated desc
                                Select request3.ID).First()
             Select New With {
                   .request = request
                   .history = request2
             }
```

In **C#**

```
var result = (from request in db.ProductRequests
              Join request2 in ProductRequestHistory
              On request.ID == request2.ProductRequestsID
              && request2.ID == (from request3 in ProductRequestHistory
                                 where request3.ProductRequestsID == request3.ID
                                 orderby request3.DateCreated desc
                                 select request3.ID).First()
              select new {
                     request = request
                     history = request2
              }
             )
```

That should do the trick.

Also, in the original SQL statement, I raccomend to change the

```
AND ProductRequestHistory.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductRequestHistory.ID ......
```

part to a `WHERE` clause, since it's not necessary to the `JOIN`.

So, in the LINQ you can use

```
Where request2.ID = (From request3 in ProductRequestHistory ......
```

Moreover, you can optimize the query pre-calculating the `TOP 1 ID` value:

```
top1id = (From request3 in ProductRequestHistory
          Where request3.ProductRequestsID = request3.ID
          Order by request3.DateCreated desc
          Select request3.ID).First()
```

And then use `Where request2.ID = top1id`.

Comment: @Jorge thanks for the c# code, i know both languages, but mainly program with vb.net

Comment: [OT] I only use it because of some debug-time limitations of VS with C#, e.g. you can't modify a function that only even contains a linq query.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken:

```
   var rusult = ProductRequests.Join(ProductRequestHistory, 
                                 p => p.ID,
                                 d => d.ProductRequestsID,
                                 (p, d) => p).where(w => w.Id == ProductRequestHistory.OrderByDescending(o=>o.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault(s=>s.ProductRequestsID == s.ID));
```